# Instagram With Asp.net to retrieve Photo Albums

Tags: asp.net, instagram

Is it Possible to retrieve albums from Instagram using Asp.net in Visual Studio 2010?

I can able to retrieve from FB,Picasa and Flickr.But I dint find any samples based on Instagram from Asp.net.

Comment: FYI only http://instagram.com/developer/ . I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Ravimallya are u aware of using Instagram(Retrieval of Photos) in IOS?

Comment: Sorry. As I told earlier, I've not tried this api. I posted URL if you might missed to get while searching. You can also go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram?sort=frequent&pageSize=50. While Googling, I got http://www.gotdotnet.ru/blogs/squall/13573/ which might be helpful to you.

Comment: its k.. i have tried that link earlier but dint help me.. anyways thanks

Comment: I tried the link which u given gotdotnet.ru/blogs/squall/13573. But it doesn't works for me